# PrimeVue Datable not updating

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, primevue

Im pretty new to Vue and JS, so Im having a hard time understanding how it all works. Im coming from Swift and maybe that is the problem.

Im trying to get a Primevue datable to update its values when changing out the values in a ref connected to it. But nothing happens on screen, however the console.log file shows the new data.

```
//Vue composition api setup()

const { flights } = getCollection("Jobs", shift.value.email, fullDay + platform.value.name)// Firebase Listener
       
        
//This function is triggered by some select buttons which changes the shift.value and platform.value so to listen for data in a different collection

const loadFlights = () => {    
  let {flights: fl} = getCollection("Jobs", shift.value.email, fullDay + platform.value.name) 
  flights.value = fl.value
  console.log('flights ref:', fl, ) // shows new the data, but the datable does not.
}
```

If Im not clicking to change to a different collection the datable updates the current collection fine. Is there some sort of "tableview.reload()" fuctionality here Im missing?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. I used watch from vue instead which triggers everytime the select value changes.
I then stored the response in a reactive parameter instead of a ref. And now it works like it should. Cant tell you why.

https://youtu.be/Qypxpm-llnQ
Program with Erik most likely can.